# why is the worst case time complexity of this algorithm O(n)?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Shouldnt the below algorithm be O(n^2) worst case? because we are iterating over the n elements in the array first, then in the worst case the array happens to only contain distinct elements, so when we check in the Set s if an element is present, we have to iterate over n elements again before adding that element, so O(n^2)?

```
# This function prints all distinct elements


def countDistinct(arr, n):

    # Creates an empty hashset
    s = set()

    # Traverse the input array
    res = 0
    for i in range(n):

        # If not present, then put it in
        # hashtable and increment result
        if (arr[i] not in s):
            s.add(arr[i])
            res += 1

    return res


# Driver code
arr = [6, 10, 5, 4, 9, 120, 4, 6, 10]
n = len(arr)
print(countDistinct(arr, n))
```

Comment: On the surface, I agree with your assessment that this is worst case `O(n^2)`. Who says it is `O(n)`?

Comment: Note that you are writing a lot of code here for something that can be done in one line: `len(set(arr))`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't think they wrote it, probably plagiarized from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-elements-in-an-array/amp/).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is there a way to find all the unique elements in that array in O(N) time then?

Comment: Every function in O(n) is in every superset of O(n), including O(n²), O(n³), O(2ⁿ)…

Comment: @greybeard You said the opposite. According to your statement, no one should think that an O(n) solution is better than O(n^2).

Comment: @MechanicPig `no one should think that an O(n) solution is better than O(n^2)` and that's true! f1(n)=log(n) is in O(n²), and f2(n)=n is in O(n). And f2 *dominates* f1.

Comment: @greybeard Although f1(n)=log(n) can be described by O(n^2), it is not the most accurate upper bound. Similarly, f2(n)=n can also be described by O(n^3). The inaccurate upper bound makes the comparison meaningless here.

Comment: @greybeard Well, I understand what you mean, so your comments are meaningless here, because OP wants an algorithm in O(n), not an algorithm in O(n^2) but not in O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusion is correct in my opinion, but the reasoning is not completely correct:

> we have to iterate over n elements again before adding that element

This is not necessary. In CPython, set is implemented as a hash table rather than a linked list (or other structures that must require `O(n)` time to append elements). Only when severe hash collisions occur (for example, all values are different but their hash values are the same), the time complexity of adding an element can reach `O(n)`.

Comment: is there a way to find all the unique elements in that array in O(N) time then?

Comment: @ferocioussprouts In my impression, hash tables should be the **best** solution *at present*, and it can find all the unique elements with `O(n)` complexity on average.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the [worst-case time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) of set lookup is O(n), and you have correctly described the scenario in which this would occur. If every element in the set was the same, there would not be any hash collisions, and this would guarantee O(1) set membership check and only one insertion for an overall O(n) runtime. If every element was *distinct* and collided with every key in the set during each membership check/insertion, that would result in O(n) add/lookup which would be O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: Hmm, why are you talking about all elements being the same? That's not what the question says, and as you showed, it's also not a worst case, so why bring it up?

Comment: Umm ... a single collision for each key doesn't necessarily result in `O(N)`.  To get `O(N)` for a lookup, you actually need *on average* for each key to collide with `O(N)` keys currently in the set.

Comment: @KellyBundy Probably because I should be heading to bed around now and completely misread the question. Fixing my answer now. Good point Stephen, this is what I meant to say but the way I wrote it made it sound like you would only collide with 1 key each time which would obviously not be O(n).

Comment: @StephenC is there a way to find all the unique elements in that array in O(N) time then?

Comment: @ferocioussprouts there is a data structure whose name eludes me at the moment that is similar to a bitmap https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap. Essentially, you create a list of length `k`, and set each value of the list to 0. If the list you are checking for distinct values from 0 to `k` you can easily set the index of the value to 1 to indicate that you have seen it before so all insertions/checks are guaranteed to be O(1). The catch is that initialization is O(k), it only works for positive integers, and they must all be between 0 and `k`. Your runtime here would be O(n + k)

Comment: @ferocioussprouts - Well your algorithm is the way ... assuming a decent hash function and non-pathological collection of array elements.   Like we said, it **>>>IS<<<** `O(N)` on average.

Comment: There is a quibble that the implementation of `set` in Python is ... implementation dependent.  But assuming that it is a hash table, then on average `O(1)` lookup should be expected.